# Using POSIX to exclude a word inside a string

Tags: python, regex, posix

Is it possible to use ONLY POSIX regular expressions to guarantee that a word does not appear inside a string??

I mean that, if i wanted to have only words that dont have "tree":

It should tell me that "I like turtles" matches.

On the other hand, it should not match "The man is on the tree"

Thanks

Comment: I assume that the second phrase should be "The man is on the **tree**"?

Comment: Why not just check for something that __doesn't__ match `tree`?

Comment: It's possible, since the complement of a regular language is a regular language, but I don't think there's any convenient way to express it.

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling. The second string is "the man is on the tree"

Comment: Also, I should point out that you don't really need a regex at all. You can just use `not 'tree' in str` as a test.

Comment: I did come up with a solution, but it uses negative lookahead, which is not supported by POSIX alone

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^([^t]|(t[^r])|(tr[^e])|(tre[^e]))*($|(t($|(r($|e$)))))
```

Comment: You edited it. This works. Your previous one was only working if tree is at the end of a sentence, I presume.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it without using Python.

Lets assume that you have stored your data in a textfile. This should do the trick:

```
grep '\tree\>' textfile
```